# Copying strings and bytes from memory to storage via storage references

Tags: solidity, string, data-types, storage-pointer, memory-pointer

What's the proper way to copy a `string` (or `bytes`) from `memory` to `storage`? When copied directly into a state variable lvalue (or into a mapping), there's no problem, but when assigning a `string memory` rvalue into a `string storage` lvalue, there's a compiler error.

The [Solidity documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/types.html#data-location-and-assignment-behaviour) suggests that it ought to be possible to assign a `memory` reference to a `storage` reference and that the behavior is that the pointed-to value in memory is copied into the pointed-to location in storage. Why is it different when the lvalue is a reference instead of a state variable or mapping?

I suppose I could code this myself in Yul, but I'd prefer to avoid re-implementing the rules regarding the handling of [short `string`/`bytes` in storage](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/internals/layout_in_storage.html#bytes-and-string).

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.15;

contract Works {
  string public thing;

  function setThing(string memory newValue) public {
    thing = newValue;
  }
}

contract AlsoWorks {
  mapping(bytes32 => string) public things;

  function setThing(bytes32 key, string memory newValue) public {
    things[key] = newValue;
  }
}

contract Fails {
  string public thing;

  function setThing(string memory newValue) public {
    string storage thingLocal = thing;
    thingLocal = newValue;
  }
}
```

---

What I'm actually trying to do here is to store a `string` at a slot that is impossible to accidentally clobber so that it is preserved across contract upgrades. A more concrete example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.15;

abstract contract MagicSlot {
  uint256 internal constant _MAGIC_SLOT = 0xcafef00dcafef00dcafef00dcafef00dcafef00dcafef00dcafef00dcafef00d;

  function _magic() internal pure returns (string storage result) {
    assembly ("memory-safe") {
      result.slot := _MAGIC_SLOT
    }
  }

  function magic() external view returns (string memory) {
    return _magic();
  }
}

contract Fails is MagicSlot {
  function setMagic(string memory newValue) public {
    // TypeError: Expression has to be an lvalue.
    // TypeError: Type string memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type string storage pointer.
    _magic() = newValue;
  }
}

contract AlsoFails is MagicSlot {
  function setMagic(string memory newValue) public {
    string storage magicRef = _magic();
    // TypeError: Type string memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type string storage pointer.
    magicRef = newValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly sure as to why there is that behavior... but if you need, I already implemented that logic in yul handling short and long strings here : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/126284/84305

Comment: Thanks. I see 2 quick improvements you could use in your code. For one, you have a bug: 0x19 + 1 != 0x20. The constant 0x19 should be 0x1f. And for the other, you can use `shl` instead of `mul` to save 2 gas on each operation. I'll take a closer look later when I'm in front of my main machine

Comment: nice catch for the 0x19 you are right, I edited my answer. However, for `shl` / `shr` vs `mul` it's the other way around, `mul` is 5 gas while `shr` / `shl` are 3 each.

Comment: Yes, `mul` is 5 gas and `shl`/`shr` are 3. Therefore, instead of `mul(x, 2)` you should write `shl(1, x)`. Likewise, instead of `div(x, 2)`, you should write `shr(1, x)`. This saves 2 gas per operation.

Comment: Ah okay I understood it the other way around. I'll leave it as it is for readability, feel free to change if you end up using the code.